# How to reverse-tab to delete tabs in Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, text-editing, text-formatting

In Outlook 365 (locally installed client, not web client) I frequently copy/paste SQL and source code snippets into emails. For example, by default after a paste operation, I invariably end up with something like this:

```
update Category
                     set CatSeqNo = @CatSeqNo
                     where CatID = @CatID
```

[image]

I'm kind of OCD about things lining up, and I prefer it like this, even in an email:

```
update Category
set CatSeqNo = @CatSeqNo
where CatID = @CatID
```

[image]

This immediately becomes a hassle in the example above. In apps such as Visual Studio and Notepad++, `SHIFT+TAB` (while highlighting the tabbed-over portion) is a quick and convenient solution. Unfortunately, in Outlook, `SHIFT+TAB` merely moves the cursor from the email body up to the subject line. So the only way I know of to get rid of all those left-tabs and achieve nice alignment, is to manually delete the tabs, either by keystrokes, or by first highlighting with the mouse (1 line at a time).

This is an inconvenient hassle. Is there anything equivalent in Outlook to `SHIFT+TAB` in VS and Notepad++?

Comment: I think easiest way would be to paste first in Notepad++, Shift+Tab there to remove the tabs, then move the resulting SQL into email client.

Comment: You have offered a workaround, not a solution. That's almost as big a pain as just doing it manually in Outlook. Holding out for something better.

Comment: There's a reason I only put it as a comment. I didn't claim it was a _perect_ solution, just that it seemed that would be the easiest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Did some search but I'm afraid that in Outlook desktop client we have no quick method for that.